# How can I get values of a rows of a JSP table in my controller class?

Tags: java, jquery, jsp

I have a table in view page (jsp) that dynamically adds rows. How can I get these row values in my controller class? 
 JSP code

```
<TABLE id="additionalContTable">
    <tr>
        <td>Email:&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input id= "confirmationEmail1"type="text" name="email" value="">
    </td>
    </tr>
    </TABLE>
```

ROWS added as on below function in JS on PLUS button click :

```
    function addContactAction()
    {
     $("#additionalContTable").append('<tr>'+
     '<td>Email:&nbsp;&nbsp;'+  
     '<input id="confirmationEmail'+rowNo+'" type="text" name="emailRow"  /></td>' +
     '</tr>');
      rowNo = rowNo +1;
    }
```

Comment: look at this link http://danielniko.wordpress.com/2012/04/17/simple-crud-using-jsp-servlet-and-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

you need to take data by HttpRequestObject. you can simply use reqOject.getParameter("rowName")
nd you can iterate it in your controller.  you will get all values